# How to sum values of ranges faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

Problem is described [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/583d171f28a0c04b7c00009c)

> Given a list of integers A, for each pair of integers (first, last) in
> list ranges, calculate the sum of the values in A between indices
> first and last (both inclusive), and return the greatest resulting
> sum.

Problem is not so trivial as it seems, because of the timeout - test lists are way too long:

> each integers-list : 100000 elements each ranges-list : 10000 elements

I have tried some solutions, and the fastest one, so far, was this: (checked with timeit, sum() is faster than loops and adding to the result, if i am right?)

```
def max_sum4(l, r):
    maxi = -1000000
    for el in r:
        if el[1] == len(l)-1:
            n=sum(l[el[0]:])
        else:
            n=sum(l[ el[0]: el[1]+1 ])
        if n>maxi:
            maxi=n
        
    
    return maxi
    #timeout, fastest one
```

Anyway, this one is not fast enough (max 12s) for the extremely long lists.

I guess that list slicing (new list created every time?) and summing in every iteration is bottleneck.
How to optimize code further, or i have to change approach, completely?
I would appreciate **HINT**, ***NOT complete solution***.

Comment: There's a mathematical formula for this, you don't need to loop.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, even when the ranges aren't sequential?

Comment: Yes, although the problem statement doesn't seem to require non-sequential ranges.

Comment: Precompute an array S, where for each k, S[k] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[k].

Comment: Sorry Barmar, but you've misread the question. It's to sum up elements of an array in a range, not to sum up elements in a range.

Comment: Use sum area tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Comment: you may use c++, which is faster by nature

Comment: @PaulHankin, thanks for the hint, you got the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cumulative sum is probably what you are looking for, should be fast, since you sum just once and then just subtract.

```py
import numpy as np

def max_sum(a, ranges):
    maxi = -np.inf
    cs = np.cumsum(a)
    for el in ranges:
        val = cs[el[1]] - (cs[el[0]-1] if el[0] > 0 else 0)
        if val > maxi:
            maxi = val
    return maxi
```

EDIT:
if `numpy` is not allowed you can calculate cumsum by yourself for example with

```py
cs = [a[0]]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    cs.append(cs[i-1] + a[i])
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you were allowed to use `numpy` for these challenges, this is definitely the solution

Comment: Thanks, tests passed, of course. I thought i will have to use numpy, but...

Comment: you dont have to use numpy if you don't want to or are not allowed, just calculate `np.cumsum` by yourself, see my edited answer. Note that this probably isn't the fastest implementation

Comment: Agreed with @DominikFicek, there is a measurable improvement in asymptotic runtime of this solution to the one that you posted. The `cumsum` used here is exactly the summed area table I pointed you at in the comment on your question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def max_sum(A, ranges):
     sums = []
     for start, end in ranges:
         sums.append(sum(A[start:end+1]))
     return max(sums)
```

Let me know if this is still too slow, it passes all their tests

Comment: Thanks, but: Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) again. :) Nice kata, def. :)

Comment: Hm... interesting, let me give it another go

Comment: The correct solution runs in O(len(A) + len(ranges)) time. This solution (which is more or less the same as the solution in the question) runs in O(len(A) * len(ranges)) time in the worst case.

Comment: The provided `numpy` solution is the way to go, didn't know 3rd party libraries were allowed, thought it had to be vanilla python